# KnockoutJS - Convention based auto-mapping using mapping plugin not working as expected

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am trying to get to grips with KnockoutJS. I have had a bit of success replicating Steven Sanderson's seminar example from mix11 (Person with Friends on Twitter) .

I am trying to extend it so that I can get JSON from my ASP.NET MVC4 controller, and automatically bind the data to the viewModel.

I managed to get it working quite quickly with manual mapping of my JSON object to knockout objects with observables, however, this is a simple model with low complexity. When I come to use this for real, the models will likely be more complicated, and manual mapping will be less attractive.

I think this being an ASP.NET MVC4 page is irrelevant, as I am getting valid JSON into the markup.

Here is the full mark up:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Person</title>
    <link href="/KnockoutSample/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script src="/KnockoutSample/Scripts/jquery-2.0.0.js"></script>

    <script src="/KnockoutSample/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
<script src="/KnockoutSample/Scripts/knockout-2.2.1.debug.js"></script>
<script src="/KnockoutSample/Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script>

</head>
<body>




<h2>Person</h2>
<p>Full name: <span data-bind="text: fullName" ></span></p>

<p>First name: <input type="text" data-bind="value: firstName" /></p>
<p>Last name: <input type="text" data-bind="value: lastName" /></p>


<h2>Friends (<span data-bind="text: friends().length"></span>)</h2>
<ol data-bind="template: { name: 'friendsTemplate', foreach:friends}"></ol>

<script id="friendsTemplate" type="text/html">
    <li>
        <input data-bind="value: fullName"/>
        <button data-bind="click: removeFriend">Remove</button>
        <label><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isOnTwitter" />Is On Twitter</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Please enter username" data-bind="value: twitterName, visible: isOnTwitter" />
    </li>
</script>
<button data-bind="click: addFriend, enable: friends().length < 5">Add Friend</button>
<button data-bind="click: save">Save</button>



<script type="text/javascript">

    function friend() {

        function instanceOfConstructor(newFriend) {
            return {
                fullName: newFriend.fullName,
                isOnTwitter: newFriend.isOnTwitter,
                twitterName: newFriend.TwitterName,
                removeFriend: function () {
                    viewModel.friends.remove(this);
                }
            };
        }
        function paramatisedConstructor(name, onTwitter, twitterName) {
            return {
                fullName: ko.observable(name),
                isOnTwitter: ko.observable(onTwitter),
                twitterName: ko.observable(twitterName),
                removeFriend: function () {
                    viewModel.friends.remove(this);
                }
            };
        }

        switch (arguments.length) {
            case 1 :
                return instanceOfConstructor(arguments[0]);
            case 3 :
                return paramatisedConstructor(arguments[0], arguments[1], arguments[2]);
        }
    }


    var viewModel = {
        firstName : ko.observable(),
        lastName: ko.observable(),
        friends: ko.observableArray(),
        addFriend: function () {
            this.friends.push(new friend("New Friend", false, null));
        },
        save: function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/KnockoutSample/Main/Person",
                type: "POST",
                data: ko.toJSON(this),
                contentType: "application/json",
            }).success(function(result){
                alert(result.message);
            }).fail(function (data) {
                alert(data);
            });
        }
    };

    viewModel.fullName = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
        return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
    }, viewModel);

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

    var initialData = '{"firstName":"Ian","lastName":"Robertson","friends":[{"isOnTwitter":false,"TwitterName":"","fullName":"Friend One"},{"isOnTwitter":true,"TwitterName":"@FriendTwo","fullName":"Friend Two"}]}';

    var tmp = ko.mapping.fromJSON(initialData);

    //Convention based auto-mapping does not work
    //ko.mapping.fromJSON(initialData, viewModel);

    //Manual mapping does work
    viewModel.firstName(tmp.firstName());
    viewModel.lastName(tmp.lastName());

    $.each(tmp.friends(), function (i, _friend) {
        viewModel.friends.push(new friend(_friend));
    });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I am hoping its possible to avoid the manual mapping at the end:

```
    //Convention based auto-mapping does not work
    //ko.mapping.fromJSON(initialData, viewModel);

    //Manual mapping does work
    viewModel.firstName(tmp.firstName());
    viewModel.lastName(tmp.lastName());

    $.each(tmp.friends(), function (i, _friend) {
        viewModel.friends.push(new friend(_friend));
    });
```

Any pointers on how I can use the mapping plugin to avoid manual mapping would be much appreciated.

UPDATE:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function friend(name, onTwitter, twitterName) {
    return {
        fullName: ko.observable(name),
        isOnTwitter: ko.observable(onTwitter),
        TwitterName: ko.observable(twitterName),
        removeFriend: function () {
            viewModel.friends.remove(this);
        }
    };
}

var initialData = '@Html.Raw(ViewBag.InitialData)';

var viewModel = {
    firstName: ko.observable(),
    lastName: ko.observable(),
    friends: ko.observableArray()
};

viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJSON(initialData, viewModel);

viewModel.save = function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("Person")",
        type: "POST",
        data: ko.toJSON(this),
        contentType: "application/json",
    }).success(function (result) {
        alert(result.message);
    }).fail(function (data) {
        alert(data);
    });
};

viewModel.addFriend = function () {
    this.friends.push(new friend("New Friend", false, null));
};

try {

    viewModel.fullName = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
        return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
    }, viewModel);

    $.each(viewModel.friends(), function (i, _friend) {
        _friend.removeFriend = function () {
            viewModel.friends.remove(this);
        }
    });

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

} catch (e) {
    alert(e);
}
```

This is almost the solution I wanted to achieve. The only thing I will continue to try and improve upon is using a jquery $.each function to add the "removeFriend" function to each friend element in the array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [fromJS](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) and toJS functions to map your viewmodel to raw data and back to viewmodel.

```
var tmp = ko.mapping.fromJS(ko.mapping.toJS(viewModel));
```

Comment: Thanks Damien. Your suggestion didn't get me closer to the solution, but it got me thinking. I dont know if its possible to remove the last niggle of the $.each approach at the end - that's almost manual mapping still...